# Manage recurring event time

Tags: code

Hello I'm trying to make a list of medications, the time to take them is recurring so I must have a repeater and an opening time.

So I created it as follows:

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" name="h-init"> -- Initial Hour
    <input type="text" name="m-init"> -- Initial minute
    <select name="repeater"> -- REPEATER
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And the I store this on a ACF field

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $_POST['postTitle'],
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_category' => array( 3, $_POST['tipo'] )
);

// insert the post into the database
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
update_field( 'hora', $_POST['hora'].':'.$_POST['minuto'], $post_id );
update_field( 'frequencia', $_POST['frequencia'], $post_id );
```

I have the start time and the repeater, I have to compare and display the next drug to be taken. A list like:

> MED1 - 18:30 PM / MED2 - 20:00 PM / MED3 - 02:00 AM / MED4: 12:00 AM

The big problem is I don't know where to start, so I started with with this code:

```
<ul class="medicamentos-list owl-carousel">
    <?php
        $the_query = new WP_Query('category_name=medicamentos&posts_per_page=-1order=ASC');
        if($the_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) :
        $the_query->the_post();
    ?>
        <li class="item">
            <?php
                if ( in_category( 'colirio' )) {
                    echo '
                        <img src="http://glaucomacontrolado.com.br/app/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/colirio-1.jpg" alt="" />
                        <h2>Colírio
                    ';
                } elseif (in_category( 'comprimido' )) {
                    echo '
                        <img src="http://glaucomacontrolado.com.br/app/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/comprimido-1.jpg" alt="" />
                        <h2>Comprimido
                    ';
                } elseif (in_category( 'pomada' )) {
                    echo '
                        <img src="http://glaucomacontrolado.com.br/app/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/pomada-1.jpg" alt="" />
                        <h2>Pomada
                    ';
                }
            ?>

                <?php the_field('hora'); ?>
                <?php the_field('frequencia'); ?>

            </h2>
        </li>
    <?php
        endwhile; else :
            echo '<li>NENHUM MEDICAMENTO CADASTRADO</li>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
        endif;
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: do you use a custom post type for the medications ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could describe what the desired output would look like or what _isn't_ happening with the code you have now.